# Multilevel model classes in Entity Framewok Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework-core

My database entity project has count about 30 columns, I would like to create clear EF Core model which many of them is grouped in several classes.

For example, overriding entity is `Sensors` and it has two elements `(Int ID, ElectricalData electricalData)`, `ElectricalData` is a seperate class which has next 3 seperate classes and two `bool` and `string` objects.

A model constructed in this way in `Add-Migration` process returns feedback that sub-entities doesn't have a primary key, but they shouldn't contain PK, because only `Sensors` class should have a primary key.

How can I solve this problem? Does this idea is correct?

Code below:

```
    public class SensorModel
    {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public ElectricalDataModel ElectricalData { get; set; }
    }

   public class ElectricalDataModel
   {
      public TensionModel Tension { get; set; }
      public CurrentModel Current { get; set; }
      public string SecurityClass { get; set; }
      public ResistanceModel Resistance { get; set; }
      public bool ReversePolarizationSecurity { get; set; }
   }

   public class TensionModel
   {
      public double Minimum { get; set; }
      public double Maximum { get; set; }
      public string Current { get; set; }
   }
   //.......................................... and so on
```

Comment: Are you seeking for [Owned Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)?

Comment: Entities must have a primary key for Entity Framework to be able to update and delete them. Do you want the entities `ElectricalDataModel` and `TensionModel` to have a primary key of `SensorModelId`?

Comment: @IvanStoev That was very helpful. All works correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking was called [Complex Types](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types), and the EF Core term is [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). By default they share the same table as the owner and are used to just logically separate (group) the related properties - exactly the goal you are describing.

The easiest way to identify a class as owned type in EF Core 2.1 is to mark it with `OwnedAttribute`:

```
[Owned]
public class ElectricalDataModel
{
    // Properties..
}

[Owned]
public class TensionModel
{
    // Properties..
}

//.......................................... and so on
```

Of course the same can be achieved via the `OwnsOne` fluent API, which also allows you to configure the column names and other attributes for the owned entity *per owner*.